# wpf different borderbrushes for different sides

Tags: wpf, border

Is it possible to set different borderbrushes for different sides e.g. left and right blue and other to grey?

(I've found only the dirty workaround
[here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/2b3fe87a-89d1-4144-8275-4098977f26c6))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - there's no other way to do it

...

Unless you build your own Decorator: http://www.wiredprairie.us/journal/2006/09/wpf_decorators_build_your_own.html

Comment: But how is it implemented in the textbox (aero style)?

Comment: if your OS is in aero, use blend to "edit a copy" of the textbox style. You'll see theyre using a custom control that inherits from Decorator. Maybe you could look into using that: http://www.wiredprairie.us/journal/2006/09/wpf_decorators_build_your_own.html